# How to force rematch?

Tags: regex, perl, inverse-match

I would like to force rematch in the following scenario - I'm trying to inverse match a qualifier after each element in a list. In other words I have:

```
"int a, b, c" =~ m{
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<qualifs>\s*(?<qualif>\bint\b|\bfloat\b)\s*+(?{print $+{qualif}  . "\n"}))
    (?<decl>\s*(?!(?&qualif))(?<ident>[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*+)\s*(?{print $+{ident} . "\n"}))

    (?<qualifsfacet>\s*\bint\b\s*+)
    (?<declfacet>[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*+)
)


^((?&qualifsfacet)*+(?!(?&decl))
                |(?&qualifs)*+(?&declfacet)
                |((?&qualifsfacet)
                (?&declfacet)(?<negdecl>\g{lastnegdecl}(,(?&decl)))
                |(?&qualifs)*+(?&declfacet)(?<lastnegdecl>\g{negdecl})
                (?# Here how to force it to retry last with new lastnegdecl)))$
                }xxs;
```

And would like to have:

```
a
int
b
int
c
int
```

As output. Currently it's only this:

```
a
int
int
```

I think this might work if there is a way to tell the regex machine to retrigger a match for the new `lastnegdecl` that is being captured.

Comment: Currently the regex matches the second alternative `(?&qualifs)*+ (?&declfacet)` so it will not try the third alternative where you define the `lastnegdecl`, right? Btw, why do you use `*+` in `(?&qualifs)*+` ? Shouldn't it be `*?` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Sorry I'm used to matching inside a nested pattern - it should try it if you put `^` and `$` which I missed. I'll edit my question now. `*+` is atomic none or more greedy I believe.

Comment: It seems like an issue that `negdecl` and `lastnegdecl` will not get defined if the sub pattern fails, but both sub patterns depend on the other being defined

Comment: @HåkonHægland I actually figured that out and put a check on the first instance like so `(?(<lastnegdecl>)\g{lastnegdecl}|)` but I found that then I can't understand why `negdecl`  isn't defined in `lastnegdecl`.

Comment: It is not clear what the bigger picture is. For example, why do you want this specific output. What are you trying to parse, is it a C program? Then why did you not use a dedicated parser like [`Marpa::R2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) or [`Regexp::Grammars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars). It might be easier to suggest alternative solutions if we know more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Well I can use clang frontend as well but my purpose is to write it on my own with pure RegEx since I find this innovative and having potential. I need this specific output so my C++ generating code can work (I'm normally embedding the Perl interpreter in native code and calling hooks on each mid-pattern code) - because it takes an identifier and then registers the type.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project yes.. So currently you are using the regex match for its side effect by calling `(?{print ...})` inside? You do not make use of the resulting match variables like `%+` after the regex match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237371/discussion-between-anarrayoffunctions-and-hakon-haegland).

Answer (score 1):

Well after some trying I finally figured it out (besides the obvious whitespace issues I had in my original post):

```
"int a, b, c" =~ m{
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<qualifs>\s*+(?<qualif>\bint\b|\bfloat\b)\s*+(?{print $+{qualif}  . "\n"}))
    (?<decl>\s*+(?!(?&qualif))(?<ident>[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*+)\s*(?{print $+{ident} . "\n"}))

    (?<qualifsfacet>\s*+(\bint\b|\bfloat\b)\s*+)
    (?<declfacet>\s*+[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*+\s*+)
)


^((?&qualifsfacet)(?!(?&decl))
                |(?&qualifs)*+(?&declfacet)
                |(?<restoutter>(?=(?&qualifsfacet)(?&declfacet)
                (?<rest>(?(<rest>)\g{rest}),(?&decl)))
                ((?&qualifs)(?&declfacet)\g{rest}|(?&restoutter)))
                |(?&qualifsfacet)(?&declfacet)(,(?&declfacet))*+)$
                }xxs;
```

Basically I'm doing a positive lookahead where `decl` are called with code but `qualifs` are not while also  concatenating `decl` inside `rest` then doing a partial match with the `qualifs` and the `rest` and if it doesn't match it goes to do the same thing again. Maybe someone can explain it better but it works. The output of the program above is:

```
a
int
b
int
c
int
```

And there is a full match.